# sum of sigma finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to demonstrate:

> Finite sum of $\sigma$ -finite measures is a $\sigma$ - finite measure.

I tried this:

Suppose there are $m$ $\sigma$ measures in a space $(\mathcal X,\mathcal A),$ denoted by $\mu_k$ with $k \in {1,\ldots,m}.$ Then exist $A_n^k$ for each $k,$ and $\mathcal X=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n^k$.

And i want to prove that $A_n=\bigcup \limits_{k=1}^{m} A_n^k$ is the decomposition of the sum measure $\mu=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{m}\mu_k$, but I have problems with the finite measure of each $A_n$.

My definition of $A_n$ is wrong?

Is an easier solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do the case $m=2$ (the general one follows by induction).

The problem is that we may have $\mu_1(A_n^2)=+\infty$.

However, if we define $B_{n_1,n_2}:=A_{n_1}^1\cap A_{n_2}^2$, then the family 
$\left(B_{n_1,n_2}\right)_{(n_1,n_2)\in\mathbb N^2}$ is countable and 
$$(\mu_1+\mu_2)\left(B_{n_1,n_2}\right) \leqslant \mu_1\left(A_{n_1}^1\right)+\mu_2\left(A_{n_2}^2\right),$$
which is finite.